# Isolating the elements of a row in python

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am working on a project where i am trying to plot the rainfall pattern of various states of my country. By using this command i fetch the data from my database:

```
 cur.execute('SELECT JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DECEMBER FROM Rainfall_In_Cm where STATE_UT = %s && DISTRICT = %s' ,(state , district))
```

The result comes in the form of a list with 1 element(the 1 row from the query output) :

```
(Decimal('17.5'), Decimal('9.9'), Decimal('8.9'), Decimal('4.0'), Decimal('9.3'), Decimal('53.8'), Decimal('227.1'), Decimal('280.90'), Decimal('125.4'), Decimal('28.1'), Decimal('5.0'), Decimal('4.7'))
```

Now i want all the elements to be in form of a list that i can use with matplotlib to plot a graph and I want to remove 'Decimal' string from infront of every value . How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is a tuple, not a list, but that is not a problem.

Casting should work for these `Decimal` objects. You can use a list comprehension:

```
#Data from your example
foo = (Decimal('17.5'), Decimal('9.9'), Decimal('8.9'), Decimal('4.0'), Decimal('9.3'), Decimal('53.8'), Decimal('227.1'), Decimal('280.90'), Decimal('125.4'), Decimal('28.1'), Decimal('5.0'), Decimal('4.7'))
bar = [float(i) for i in foo]
```

If you want to have rather integers, use:

```
bar = [int(i) for i in foo]
```

Comment: If the answer suits your needs, please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so other users know it works...